# SOQL - Task query that includes Case Subject

Tags: soql, case, polymorphic

I need to run an SOQL that generates activities due next week (for a Conga Composer Solution).  Some of the activities are related to Cases.  The What.Name for cases is the Case number which has little meaning for our management.  IS there a way to return an additional field that is the Case.Subject?  I was hoping to use the TypeOf feature, but Salesforce was not willing to enable that for my production org.  Below is a snippet of the SOQL that does not yet include the Case.Subject.

```
SELECT Owner.Name, What.Name, What.Type, WhatId 
FROM TASK 
where ActivityDate = NEXT_WEEK 
ORDER BY What.Name ASC, ActivityDate DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TYPEOF is currently available as a Developer Preview as part of the SOQL Polymorphism feature. For more information on enabling TYPEOF for your organization, contact Salesforce.

Refer [TYPEOF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm)

So, for the time being you need to perform separate SOQL query to fetch Case Subject based on `What.type`